# Split a string at each number

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

The idea is to take a string of letters and numbers much like an algebraic expression with indices and split them up while including the index with the corresponding letter. For example: You take the expresson `2x^3`and it would be split into an array like so `["2","x^3"]`

As of right now I have tried to work with the letters and the number can come later but this is what I have got so far:

```
expression.split(/([a-z])/);
```

This takes the string and splits it at every number. I'm not good at regular expression so some help on including the index of a letter with the split would be much appreciated.

Comment: `string.split(...)` will not work here. Do yourself a favor, write down 5 examples of input and output you expect, and include some extra complicated examples in there. Then think about your algorithm. Good luck

Comment: We really need more examples, because right now I have no idea where to start. Give a few other examples, some complex ones.

Comment: If JS used a normal regex engine it would simply be `(?<=\d)(?=\D)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for :

```js
var string = '2x^3ui3+3-ddez2';
var regex = /(\D*\d)/g;
var array = string.match(regex);
```

[image: result]